# When is $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y} \, \text{d} x \, \text{d} y = 2 \int_0^1 f(t) \log\left(\frac{t}{1-t}\right) \, \mathrm{d} t$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Double integrals of this type sometimes appear when using differentiation under the integral sign with respect to two variables. Therefore, I am interested in reducing them to (simpler) single integrals. If $f$ is Hölder continuous, i.e. $f \in C^{0,\alpha}([0,1])$ for some $\alpha \in (0,1]$, the integrals in the following calculation exist and all manipulations are easy to justify ($F$ is an arbitrary antiderivative of $f$):
\begin{align}
D(f) &\equiv \int \limits_0^1 \int \limits_0^1 \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y} \, \text{d} x \, \text{d} y = 2 \int \limits_0^1 \int \limits_0^y \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y} \, \text{d} x \, \text{d} y \\
&= 2 \int \limits_0^1 \int \limits_0^y \frac{f(y) - f(y-t)}{t} \, \text{d} t \, \text{d} y = 2 \int \limits_0^1 \int \limits_t^1 \frac{f(y) - f(y-t)}{t} \, \text{d} y \, \text{d} t \\
&= 2 \int \limits_0^1 \frac{F(1) - F(1-t) - F(t) + F(0)}{t} \, \mathrm{d} t = 2 \int \limits_0^1 \log(t) [f(t) - f(1-t)] \, \mathrm{d} t \\
&= 2 \int \limits_0^1 \log\left(\frac{t}{1-t}\right) f(t) \, \mathrm{d} t \equiv S(f) \, .
\end{align}
However, this identity is also true for many less regular functions. The integral on the right-hand side exists for all $f$ in the weighted $L^1$ space $$A \equiv L^1 \left([0,1], \left\lvert\log \left(\frac{\cdot}{1-\cdot}\right)\right\rvert \lambda^1\right)$$
($\lambda^1$ is the one-dimensional Lebesgue measure). It contains the function $g \equiv t \mapsto \left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-1}$, for which we have $S(g) = \pi^2$, while $D(g)$ does not exist. Therefore, I would like to find the set
$$B = \{f \in A : D(f) \text{ exists and } D(f) = S(f)\} \subsetneq A$$
on which the above equation holds.

---

In a first attempt, I have tried to work with
$$ C \equiv L^1 \left([0,1], - \log \left[\cdot (1-\cdot)\right] \lambda^1\right) = L^1 ([0,1],\lambda^1) \cap A \, .$$
$f \in C$ has an absolutely continuous antiderivative, so we can work backwards to show
$$ S(f) = 2 \int \limits_0^1 \int \limits_t^1 \frac{f(y) - f(y-t)}{t} \, \text{d} y \, \text{d} t \stackrel{?}{=} 2 \int \limits_0^1 \int \limits_0^y \frac{f(y) - f(y-t)}{t} \, \text{d} t \, \text{d} y \, ,$$
but I do not know how to justify changing the order of integration here. Tonelli's theorem does the trick for monotone functions, but according to numerical calculations $S(f) = D(f)$  holds for other $f \in C$ as well, which leaves me with the following questions:

> 1. Can we prove that the order of integration may be changed or is there an alternative way to show that $C \subset B$ holds? (No! See edit.)
> 2. What is the largest subset of $B$ (maybe even $B$ itself?) we can find?

---

Some examples ($\mathrm{G}$ is Catalan's constant):
\begin{align}
D(\arctan) \stackrel{\text{Hölder cont.}}{=} S(\arctan) &= 2 \mathrm{G} - \frac{\pi^2}{16} - \frac{\pi}{4}\log(2) + \frac{1}{4} \log^2(2) \\
D(\log^3) \stackrel{\text{monotone}}{=} S(\log^3) &= 2 \pi^2 + \frac{2\pi^4}{15} + 12 \zeta(3)\\
D\left(t \mapsto \frac{\log(1-t)}{t^{3/2}}\right) \stackrel{?}{=} S\left(t \mapsto \frac{\log(1-t)}{t^{3/2}}\right) &= \frac{2\pi^2}{3} - 16 \log(2) (1 - \log(2))
\end{align}
The last function is neither Hölder continuous nor monotone, so it is unclear whether the integrals are equal. Mathematica gives approximately $3.1754$ for the double integral as opposed to $3.1766$ for the single integral, so there is numerical evidence, but a proof would be better, obviously.

---

**Edit 26 April 2020**

The answers to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3627512/is-there-a-set-a-subset-0-1-such-that-int-a-times-a-textc-frac-ma) question show that there are measurable sets $M \subset [0,1]$ whose indicator function $1_M$ lies in $C$ (obvious) but not in $B$, since
$$\int \limits_0^1 \int \limits_0^1 \frac{\lvert 1_M(x) - 1_M(y) \rvert}{\lvert x-y \rvert} \, \mathrm{d} x \, \mathrm{d} y = 2 \int \limits_{M \times M^\text{c}} \frac{\mathrm{d} x \, \mathrm{d} y}{\lvert x-y \rvert} = \infty \, .$$
This confirms fedja's comment and disproves $C \subset B$, so the first question is obsolete.

Comment: Consider the LHS as $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\iint_{x,y\in[0,1]:|x-y|>\varepsilon}$. Trying to show that the double integral on the left is a Lebesgue integral for all $f\in C$ is hopeless: it just isn't. However, if $f$ is good enough so that the LHS exists as a Lebesgue integral, the definitions coincide.